# image display after second orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I use the following code to save and restore an image, it works after the first orientation changed (portrait to landscape). However, after I rotate it back to the portrait mode(2nd orientation change), the image disappeared which I don't want to happen.

Please help

save image code

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("selectedImage", yourSelectedImage);


}
```

restore code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
if(savedInstanceState !=null){
        Bitmap yourSavedBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("selectedImage");
        image.setImageBitmap(yourSavedBitmap);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different variables to save instance and restore instance:

```
yourSelectedImage
```

and

```
yourSavedBitmap
```

So I assume that you are setting the var yourSelectedImage from somewhere else in your code, serialize it to saved instance, but after restoring the variable is empty. If possible put something like :

```
yourSelectedImage = yourSavedBitmap
```

In your restore instance code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Bitmap bmp;
private ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    // first time the app is started get the bitmap from unknown source.
    if(savedInstanceState == null) { 
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file location string");
    // after orientation change get your saved bitmap
    } else { 
        bmp = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("selectedImage");
    }
    image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putParcelable("selectedImage", bmp );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I can answer it by myself now.
I put a preferenceManger to store the Uir as a string:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString(selectImage,"selected").commit();
```

and recall it for everytime the app is created:

```
savedImage = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("selectImage", "-1");
    try {
       if (savedImage != null) {
           InputStream imageStream = null;
           try {
               imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream((Uri.parse(savedImage)));
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
           image.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);

       }
    } catch (Throwable e){
       e.printStackTrace();

    }
```